# Writing a custom Bootstrap 5 nav walker for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-5, wp-nav-walker

How to create custom wordpress bootstrap 5 navwalker??

```
 <nav class="main-menu sticky-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main-menu-inner">
                <div class="main-menu-logo">
          <a href="https://localhost">
            <img src="logo-dark.png" alt="logo" />
          </a>
        </div>
                  <ul class=" main-nav-menu " ><li id="menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-89 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children  nav-item menu-item-179 menu-has-sub has-sub-child  active active active"><a   title="Home" class=" menu-has-sub has-sub-child " href="https://localhost">Home<span class="icon"></span></a>
<ul class=" " id="homeMenu" >
    <li id="menu-item-173" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-89 current_page_item  nav-item menu-item-173 active"><a   title="Main Layout" class=" menu-has-sub has-sub-child " href="https://shtheme.com/demosd/ziptech/">Main Layout</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  nav-item menu-item-175"><a   title="IT Solutions" class=" menu-has-sub has-sub-child " href="https://localhost">IT Solutions</a></li>
</ul>
<li id="menu-item-226" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  nav-item menu-item-226"><a   title="Contact Us" class=" menu-has-sub has-sub-child " href="contacts">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>        <div class="main-menu-right">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-toggler">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="search-toggler">
            <i class="base-icon-search-1"></i>
          </a>
                    <div class="header-contact-btn">
            <a href="contacts" class="theme-btn-6">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
                  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I try but I can't
Please help me .
I am a beginner in developing wordpress pages